Improve speed of creating keyframes
See edit below.
We are looking to visualize scientific data in Blender as animation tracks. The data on every frame is important, including even small fluctuations, so interpolating between keyframes is not an option.
Currently, we use a Python script in Blender to load the data and loop through it, adding a separate keyframe for every animation frame (30 fps), but this seems to quickly overload Blender's animation system, requiring 12 seconds for a 1 minute recording of data. This is just test data. Recordings upwards of 20-30 minutes will be normal.
We had started making a custom visualization pipeline, but we cannot maintain that, so the power and versatility of Blender will be needed.
I looked into a hack way of putting the data in a motion capture file and then importing that, but this will be too awkward going forward, I think.
So my question: is there any reasonable way to do frame-by-frame animations in Blender?
EDIT:
Based on the helpful comments from @TheLabCat, @Robin Betts, and @Alexandre Marcati, I made a minimal example that runs >10x faster and works as expected.
Keyframe interpolation mode was changed to "CONSTANT".
The important changes were:

Make sure Animation Data is first cleared whenever re-running the script.
Create new F-curves for an Action attribute of the Animation Data.
Add empty Keyframe Points to the F-Curve with "fcurve.keyframe_points.add()"
Insert the data into each Keyframe by setting the "keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui" attribute of each animation channel corresponding to a given F-Curve.

Here is the data:
https://gist.github.com/rennis250/585b1d6efaeedf08441260aa5a7b0619
Here is the code:
import os
import bpy
import mathutils

from mathutils import Vector
from itertools import chain

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class AnimateData():
    def __init__(self):
        self.poses_df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('./aligned_poses.csv'))

        self.init_ori = mathutils.Quaternion((0.0, 0.0, 0.1, -0.995))
        self.obj = bpy.context.scene.objects['Obj1']
        self.obj_curves = {}

    def init_fcurves(self):
        if self.obj.animation_data is not None:
            self.obj.animation_data_clear()

        self.obj.animation_data_create()
        self.obj.animation_data.action = bpy.data.actions.new(self.obj.name + 'Action')
        
        loc_fcurves = [self.obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.new('location', index=index) for index in range(3)]
        rot_fcurves = [self.obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.new('rotation_quaternion', index=index) for index in range(4)]
        scale_fcurves = [self.obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.new('scale', index=index) for index in range(3)]
        
        for fcurve in chain(loc_fcurves, rot_fcurves, scale_fcurves):
            fcurve.keyframe_points.add(len(self.poses_df))
            for i in range(len(self.poses_df)):
                fcurve.keyframe_points[i].interpolation = 'CONSTANT'
        
        self.obj_curves[self.obj.name] = ({
            'location': loc_fcurves,
            'rotation': rot_fcurves,
            'scale': scale_fcurves,
        })


    def execute(self):
        self.init_fcurves()
        
        for frame_num in range(len(self.poses_df)):
            bpy.context.scene.frame_set(frame_num)                

            x = self.poses_df["translation_x"][frame_num]
            y = self.poses_df["translation_y"][frame_num]
            z = self.poses_df["translation_z"][frame_num]

            # convert to blender coords
            coordinates = [x, z, -1.0*y]

            rot_x = self.poses_df["rotation_x"][frame_num]
            rot_y = self.poses_df["rotation_y"][frame_num]
            rot_z = self.poses_df["rotation_z"][frame_num]
            rot_w = self.poses_df["rotation_w"][frame_num]

            # convert to blender coords
            curr_quat = mathutils.Quaternion((rot_w, rot_x, rot_z, -1.0*rot_y))

            # original approach, was slow, now faster
            #
            # self.obj.location = coordinates
            # self.obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", index=-1, frame=frame_num)
            # self.obj.rotation_quaternion = curr_quat @ self.init_ori
            # self.obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=-1, frame=frame_num)
            # self.obj.scale = [0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
            # self.obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="scale", index=-1, frame=frame_num)

            # alternative approach, even faster and same visual results as above 
            # 
            obj_fcurves = self.obj_curves[self.obj.name]
            obj_fcurves['location'][0].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, coordinates[0]]
            obj_fcurves['location'][1].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, coordinates[1]]
            obj_fcurves['location'][2].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, coordinates[2]]
            
            rot = curr_quat @ self.init_ori
            obj_fcurves['rotation'][0].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, rot[0]]
            obj_fcurves['rotation'][1].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, rot[1]]
            obj_fcurves['rotation'][2].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, rot[2]]
            obj_fcurves['rotation'][3].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, rot[3]]
            
            obj_fcurves['scale'][0].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, 0.001]
            obj_fcurves['scale'][1].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, 0.001]
            obj_fcurves['scale'][2].keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui = [frame_num, 0.001]


anim_data_obj = AnimateData()
anim_data_obj.execute()


The title of the question doesn’t really reflect the actual problem very well, unless you are asking two questions in one, which you generally want to avoid. Are you asking how to change the interpolation to something like linear or constant instead of B-spline, or is that taken care of?

How many animation channels are you adding per frame? I’ve done per-frame animation of 8 or so at a time for a music visualizer, and Blender was done almost instantaneously, so I suspect poor code.

I'll try to come up with a better title. My apologies.
Thanks!
I would prefer no interpolation. The animation runs at 30 fps and there are 30 keyframes per second. Rather than say, 3 interpolated keyframes at frames 0, 10, and 29.
We have 6 objects, some of which rotate/scale and some of which don't. Total animation channels per frame is 37.
I used keyframe_insert. Profiling shows that this is where performance drops. I've learned about obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.new and using that interface is about 10x faster, but transform values get locked to 0.
I will update my question.

Right, I’ll go look at my script. Meanwhile, constant interpolation is about as close to “off” as you’re going to get: A channel stays at a value until it arrives at a new keyframe. That really should be a separate question, but here you go.

Would a sample chunk of input file, help, here, for folks to test approaches?

I'm using a keyframe_insert method as well. What system are you running this on? Can I have a look at your Python code, and as @RobinBetts suggested, a sample of the input data?

Thanks both! I will trim the code down to a minimal example and provide data. Will take me a few minutes.

After a brief test, rendering those 8 channels for a 5 minute audio file took a few seconds, so, I think the times line up.You can do things to make the UI update during a script run, I think, and even add a progress bar. I'll look into that.

In making the minimal example, I think you helped me realize the issue. It now runs much faster and works as expected. I will update the question above with the code + data sample.

... a summary answer from one of you, when the time comes, even if the  problem is solved (or just ameliorated) in the commentary, would be great.

For having no interpolation between keyframes you should set the interpolation mode of the keyframes to "constant" (that means the value will stay constant until it gets to the next keyframe). Not sure how to set that through code, but shouldn't be very complicated.

Summary answer:
Previously, I was blindly using keyframe_insert on objects to add animation data to each F-Curve channel (e.g., x/y/z location). This was inefficient. I wrongly assumed Blender must interpolate between a handful of keyframes, which would have conflicted with our animation intentions.
Solution (see code above):
(1) Clear Animation data when starting the script
(2) Create new F-curves for an Action attribute
(3) Add empty Keyframe Points with fcurve.keyframe_points.add()
(4) Insert the data into each Keyframe by setting the "keyframe_points[frame_num].co_ui" attribute
